# vim: moving to the n-th next tab

Tags: vim, tabs, navigation

I am trying to improve my navigation between different tabs. I learned that one can use

```
:tabn
:tabp
```

to change the current tab to the next and previous tab.

I would like to do something like to be able to move to the 4th previous or next tab. But while

```
:4 tabp
```

works just fine, the command

```
:4 tabn
```

alway switches to the tab at the 4th (absolute) position. Can anyone reproduce that behavior? And what might cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works inconsistently, but as documented (see @mMontu's answer). You can change this with a mapping; for example, to override `gt` to go to the `[count]`'th next tab page instead of the absolute one:

```
:noremap <expr> gt ':<C-U>' . (v:count > 1 ? (tabpagenr() + v:count - 1) % tabpagenr('$') + 1 : '') . 'tabnext<CR>'
```

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this behavior, an it matches the documentation:

```
:tabn[ext]              *:tabn* *:tabnext* *gt*
<C-PageDown>                *CTRL-<PageDown>* *<C-PageDown>*
gt                  *i_CTRL-<PageDown>* *i_<C-PageDown>*
        Go to the next tab page.  Wraps around from the last to the
        first one.

:tabn[ext] {count}
{count}<C-PageDown>
{count}gt   Go to tab page {count}.  The first tab page has number one.



:tabp[revious] {count}
:tabN[ext] {count}
{count}<C-PageUp>
{count}gT   Go {count} tab pages back.  Wraps around from the first one
        to the last one.
```

But I haven't noticed this before, as I use those commands without count. When I need to switch to a tabpage that isn't the next or the previous one I use `{count}gt`. To avoid counting the tabpages I use some settings to display numbers on the tab label - see `:help setting-tabline` (or `:help setting-guitablabel` if you use gVim).